# T-SQL: select data which datediff between dates exceed maximum unit

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table with two `DateTime` columns, `start` & `end`

I have a stored procedure which has a line like

```
select 
    ...
   ...
where 
   datediff(second, start, end) > xxx`
```

I know for unit = second,  the maximum difference between `start` and `end` is around 68 years.

Currently there are some false legacy data, which the difference between `start` and `end` is over 68 years, and when it came across this stored procedure, it will produce overflow error.

What I am trying to do is to write another script to select all such false data so that we can patch them, how can I do that? How can I select some records to fix the error which producing the error itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, is it really necessary to do this to one second accuracy.  After all:

```
where datediff(minute, start, end) > xxx / 60
```

or:

```
where datediff(hour, start, end) > xxx / (60 * 60)
```

but . . . if that won't do, you can try:

```
where dateadd(hour, xxx / (60 * 60),
              dateadd(second, xxx % (60 * 60), start)
             ) > end
```

EDIT:

Actually, your problem is with the dates, not the `xxx` value.  So, this should also work:

```
where dateadd(second, xxx, start) > end
```

This will work as long as `xxx` is an integer and `start` is not way too big (near the end of the range of whatever type it is).

Comment: This is quick and nice solution, but in my case, yes...as the stored procedure is in production and my senior(s) do not want to change any production code whenever it is possible...(which means if I can explain to them it is impossible to do this using second unit, I can change the stored procedure and this solution will be an accepted solution)

Answer (score 1):

Considering CASE statements resolve from left to right, you could try

```
Declare @YourTable table (id int,start datetime,[end] datetime)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'1930-01-01','2016-09-25'),   -- Greater than 2.14B seconds
(2,'2016-09-24','2016-09-25')    -- Something more reasonable

Select *
 from @YourTable
 Where case when DateDiff(MINUTE,[start],[end]) > (2147483647/60) then 2147483647 else DateDiff(SECOND,[start],[end]) end > 100000
```

Returns (**without an exception**)

```
id  start                   end
1   1930-01-01 00:00:00.000 2016-09-25 00:00:00.000
```

> **EDIT**

I should add the trap of minutes allows for 4,080 years vs 68.  Also, the default value of 2147483647 could be a more reasonable number or even 0 indicating suspect data.